# Can JPA join to a codes table when part of join clause requires a hard coded value?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I would like the resulting entity to contain all the columns from table1, plus the description from codes1.

If I were to do this in SQL I would write it as follows:

```
select table1.*, codes1.description
from table1
inner joing codes1 where codes1.code = table1.status_code 
                     and codes1.group = 'status'
```

I have done this with a native query, but would like to do this using straight JPA if possible.

**Codes Table:**

```
Group   Code  Description
status  a     status code a
status  b     status code b
other   a     other code a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we imagine 2 objects: Table1 and Code1. 
Your class Table1 contains of course Code1.

In "straight JPA" or jpql you select an object so the query will be:

```
select t from Table1 t where t.code1.group = 'status'
```

The join is automaticaly done by the mapping (@OneToOne, @ManyToOne...).